# Normal QQ-plot interpretation

Tags: qq-plot

I seek help interpreting this qqplot.

Am I correct that data points near the mean are reasonably normal, but data points away from the mean tend to be too far off, therefore the data is fat-tailed?

Secondly the data appear to be symmetric (unskewed) ?

Thanks for your help!
There is a very nice post about qq plot interpretation, but i would still like confirmation that i am comparing correctly with that post's templates.

[image]

Comment: No. Your data is heavily tailed.

Comment: @SmallChess: thx!